# Can indexing help even if your query doesn't have a WHERE Clause in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I'm having a problem on optimizing the query.

I have a table that has a 70+Million rows in it and it doesn't have an index, I want to put an index for it. I'll just ask if putting an index on it will help even if the queries executed for that specific table doesn't have a WHERE Clause?

i.e.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_1 on Table
(
 Column1,
 Column2,
 Column3
)
```

Will the query below be optimized if I selected the specific columns which the index was created and without a `WHERE Clause`?

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM Table
```

I know that the WHERE Clause will make the an INDEX SEEK on the execution plan, but what if index was created on the table and no WHERE clause included on the query, will it run fast too?

Comment: index will not help for this query

Comment: why is that? can you explain further? many thanks! =)

Comment: index is needed to speed up seeking, you're not seeking any values, you're just reading table

Comment: the only possible speed up can be if table has 100000+ columns and your query actually reads only 3 of them, then index on these 3 columns will be used during reading instead of full table, this can be faster because of less IO

Comment: you mean to say, this will help without the where clause? let's say i have a table that has many columns, then i put an index for the only 3 of them, then i created a query that selects the specific columns where i did put an index on, but note: theres no WHERE clause. will this help?

Comment: yes, if all columns in select clause can be found in some index - this index will be used instead of actual table, file with index usually less than table (or even cached in memory), so pure read will be faster

Comment: but in your case I don't think that index will help, 70+M rows even from index will be read from disk and it will take some time, why do you need to read all of them?

Comment: Indexes are also used if you want to sort the table (it’s much easier if you already have something sorted), and if you want to join the table to another (which implicitly looks for a match). BTW what happened to your primary key?

Answer (score 0):

by default the primary key is the index.  so if you don't have a primary key or any indexes, then the index will help speed up the queries exponentially.

Comment: Theres no PK on the table, thats my problem, will the query still be optimized by the help of the index even if I dont USE a WHERE clause?

Comment: If you add an index, that index will automatically be your new primary key that you didn't have.  An index should always be a candidate key.  But it will slow down your inserts and deletes, so if this table is static and nonchanging, it would probably be worth it.  But if you do need to do a lot of changes to the table often, then it would be best to normalize the table and separate it into two or three tables, and join the two up when you need to do selects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does, but not so much.

You can read more [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-indexes.htm) :

> An index helps speed up SELECT queries and WHERE clauses.

Comment: so you mean to say index will still help even if i dont use a WHERE clause on my query?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is definitely work. Using "Where" clause is good or say best, the reason is where clause filter the data which good to narrow the search area.

As your question, good to create primary key on main column and best if it is int with auto increment.  The reason is primary key automatically create a clustered index which is same order as physical data's order, so very fast than non-clustered. Even you not use where condition its work with efficient way.

If you already have primary key and you frequently used other column without using "where" clause, then make non-clusterd index. But not recommend more than 4 or 5 (there is no rule, but avoid non-clustered index much more, which decrease the performance)

Understand index.

http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/what-is-an-index/

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1206/understanding-sql-server-indexing/

I am not sure, but view index will help you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms191432.aspx

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-indexed-views-the-basics/